# How can I get a Postgresql error number in psql?

Tags: postgresql, errors, psql

How can I access the numeric code of an error in `psql`?

For example, in this case I would like to get the value 23503 ("foreign_key_violation") as documented here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html

```
postgres=# insert into t values('bb');
ERROR:  insert or update on table "t" violates foreign key constraint "fd"

-- How can I see the numeric error code here?
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set the `VERBOSITY` special variable to `sqlstate`, which will cause the SQLSTATE code to be printed after any failed statement in the current session:

```
\set VERBOSITY sqlstate
```

Alternatively, you can print the SQLSTATE code on demand:

```
\echo :LAST_ERROR_SQLSTATE
```

Answer (score 5):

mustaccio's answer is good, but if all that you need is to see the SQLSTATE of the error you just got in `psql`, the simplest way is to run

```
\errverbose
```

Note that the SQLSTATE is not always a number.